# Installing a package from a GitHub repository

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

My problem is that when I try to install a package of mine with the version set to a certain git branch my build is breaking because the repository doesn't house the `dist` folder which my npm package does.

Here is how I want to install the package.
`@me/myPkg": "github:me/myPkg#myBranch`

So should my repository include the dist folder or what's the best practice in this case? I don't want to publish my dist package onto github because then I would have weird merge conflicts because the dist folder is containg all of my type declaration and minified javascript files, but maybe this the preferred way?

Another thought I had was to have a postinstall script in my package.json which built the source files but then I would have to have the devDependencies installed as well and npm install doesn't install them for dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

How are you publishing your package? For instance, I have a [GitHub Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions) setup on my repositories that, when commits are made to `master`, will automatically perform several steps

- Run an `npm install` Setup Git Credential variables (for later
  process)
- Run `npm test` (and fail whole process if tests fail)
- Run
  `npm run release` (I use `standard-version` for auto version
  incrementing and Changelog creation, and do this prior to build so
  the version can be reflected in the built code)
- Run `npm run build`
- Run `npm run publish` to push to npm
- Commit my version update as a
  tag to Git

My GitHub Action does all of this in a temp container it spins up for the build process. Once it is done, the whole container is tossed. I use an `.npmignore` file to tell `publish` what I don't want in the final package (note files, build tools, etc).

Comment: That is not really what I was looking for. I'm more interested in what do you with the results of your "npm run build". Do you store that only in your npm package or do you store it in the repository as well? Because if not, how do consumers installing your package using a github url then use your built source files?

For reference here is my repo https://github.com/hornta/minesweeper I do manual releases instead of automatic releases but that does not matter to my question I believe.

Comment: Your `/dist` is part of your published package, but not part of your repo.

Comment: The other part of this are the `main` or `module` entries in your `package.json`, which are file pointers to your builds final entry point. Say you build from `./src/index.js`, creating `./dist/mypackage.mjs` as an es module and `./dist/mypackage.cjs.js` as a CommonJs package. Those (`/dist` paths) are the paths you put in those keys in your `package.json`, which tell future package consumers where your built packages reside in your deployed package.